# How to build Selenium environment with docker and launch chrome

Tags: node.js, selenium, docker, e2e-testing

I'd like to use the docker to launch the Selenium environment and e2e test with my local mac.

If it is Selenium currently created in the docker environment, the test will go through, but chrome browser will not start up.

If "selenium-standalone start" is done in my local mac, chrome will start up.

Somebody let me know if there is a reason why chrome does not start up when built with docker?

The reproduction procedure is as follows

**Start docker**

```
docker run -i -t -p 4444:4444 --rm --name e2e-test  selenium/standalone-chrome:3.1.0
```

**local with npm install webdriverio**

```
$ mkdir -p webdriverio-test
$ cd webdriverio-test
$ npm install webdriverio --save-dev
```

**Execute "wdio repl chrome"**

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/wdio repl chrome
```

**result**

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/wdio repl chrome
[11:48:07]  DEBUG   Queue has stopped!
[11:48:07]  DEBUG   You can now go into the browser or use the command line as REPL
[11:48:07]  DEBUG   (To exit, press ^C again or type .exit)
>
```

chrome does not start up.

**docker log when "./node_modules/.bin/wdio repl chrome" is executed**

$ ./node_modules/.bin/wdio repl chrome

```
2018-04-11 03:22:54.699:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @290ms
03:22:54.700 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
03:23:25.398 INFO - SessionCleaner initialized with insideBrowserTimeout 0 and clientGoneTimeout 1800000 polling every 180000
03:23:25.420 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{rotatable=true, locationContextEnabled=true, loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@56231b66, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, requestOrigins={name=webdriverio, version=4.12.0, url=http://webdriver.io}}]])
03:23:25.433 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{rotatable=true, locationContextEnabled=true, loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@56231b66, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, requestOrigins={name=webdriverio, version=4.12.0, url=http://webdriver.io}}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320) on port 11322
Only local connections are allowed.
03:23:26.005 INFO - Detected dialect: OSS
03:23:26.021 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{rotatable=true, locationContextEnabled=true, loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@56231b66, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, requestOrigins={name=webdriverio, version=4.12.0, url=http://webdriver.io}}]]
```

The procedure by which chrome starts up is as follows

**install selenium-standalone and start selenium-standalone in local mac.**

```
$ npm install selenium-standalone@latest -g
$ selenium-standalone install

$ selenium-standalone start
```

**Execute "wdio repl chrome"**

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/wdio repl chrome
```

**result**

chrome will start up

**selenium-standalone log when "./node_modules/.bin/wdio repl chrome" is executed**

```
12:25:15.793 INFO - /status: Executing GET on /status (handler: Status)
Selenium started

12:25:35.625 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession@538ac7ad
12:25:35.626 INFO - /session: Executing POST on /session (handler: BeginSession)
12:25:35.681 INFO - Capabilities are: Capabilities {browserName: chrome, handlesAlerts: true, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, loggingPrefs: org.openqa.selenium.logging..., requestOrigins: {name: webdriverio, url: http://webdriver.io, version: 4.12.0}, rotatable: true}
12:25:35.684 INFO - Capabilities {browserName: chrome, handlesAlerts: true, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, loggingPrefs: org.openqa.selenium.logging..., requestOrigins: {name: webdriverio, url: http://webdriver.io, version: 4.12.0}, rotatable: true} matched class org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
Starting ChromeDriver 2.36.540469 (1881fd7f8641508feb5166b7cae561d87723cfa8) on port 40458
Only local connections are allowed.
12:25:36.939 INFO - Detected dialect: OSS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome
    container_name: chrome
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Dwebdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps=
```

https://gist.github.com/GetoXs/1d1469b4fb4ac83d39e7efc3d24cd630

Answer (score 0):

Treat the docker container as a remote selenium. In your code you must use a RemoteWebDriver and connect it using the 4444 port. Chrome will run inside the container with no graphical feedback (you won't see the Chrome running)

Regards